# How to center the text larger than the container?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code:

```css
#add_cal_in {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f38268;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="add_cal_in">M</span>
```

If you run this code, you can see that the text "M" is not centered as I imagined. It works fine if you change the `font-size` to 30px or smaller. How did that happen? And how can I center the "M" right in the middle?

Another thing is although the "M" is not HORIZONTALLY centered, it seems that the "M" is still VERTICALLY centered. BUT, if I change the "M" to a "+", it will not be centered neither HORIZONTALLY nor VERTICALLY. BTW, it works perfectly in Chrome 53, I found that after I upgraded my Chrome.

Sorry about the poor English, hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: The 'M' isn't really in a container though. You've given a span a width which a font-size of 50px will expand beyond.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Flexbox` and if you set `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` it will always center text in span.

```css
span {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f38268;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<span>M</span>
<span>+</span>
<span>A</span>
```

Another option is to use pseudo-element to add letter and use `position: absolute` and `transform: translate` to center it.

```css
span {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f38268;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
span:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  content: 'M';
  color: green;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: Both of your solutions are wonderful~ THANKS. But as you can see, the "+" is not vertically centered, not visually. My guess is that the "+" is not vertically centered itself. I guess I can use pseudo-element to fix this.

Comment: It looks like there is one pixel that is problem, try with padding-top: 1px https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1696/

Answer (score 1):

I think just change the width and height with 100%..

```css
#add_cal_in {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f38268;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="add_cal_in">M</span>
```

Comment: You may misunderstand what I mean. I want the text to be centered in the 30*30 box. The width and the height is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can center letter horizontally by script:

```js
var marginLeft = ($('#add_cal_in').width() - $('.letter').width())/2;
$('.letter').css('margin-left', marginLeft+'px');
```

```css
#add_cal_in {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f38268;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="add_cal_in"><span class="letter">M</span></span>
```

Comment: It's a good idea! But still I was wondering if there is a way without the script. Flexbox seems can solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```css
#add_cal_in {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #f38268;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="add_cal_in">M</span>
```

Comment: With display: inline; height:30px; is useless; because it's an inline element